If the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n$ converges for positive $a_n$, what can we say about the sequence $a_n$?
Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers and assume that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n < \infty.$$
What can we then say about $a_n$? There are a few obvious things; $a_n\to 0$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. I would like a result along the lines of: For all sufficiently large $n$, $a_n\le b_n$ for some summable sequence $(b_n)$ not depending on $a_n$. I feel like $a_n$ should behave like $1/n^2$ asymptotically, but I have not been able to show anything like that. Any help is appreciated.

$a_n$ can be $\frac 1 {n \ln n}$ for infinitely many values of $n$.

@geetha290krm Oh, I suppose. So the asymptotic behaviour is not smaller than $1/n^2$. But still, it can't be of order $\frac{1}{n \log(n)}$ for too many $n$, otherwise the original series wouldn't converge...

Given any $(b_n)$, we can make $a_n >b_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

Letting $c_n:=na_n$, your question is equivalent to: Let $(c_n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers and assume that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n < \infty.$$
What can we then say about $c_n$?

@geetha290krm Wait really? That's not clear to me

@geetha290krm, it is false since $na_n \rightarrow 0$, you have $a_n = o(1/n)$ thus for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there are finitely many $n$ (depending on $\varepsilon$) such that $a_n > \varepsilon/n$. It is true however that for all $(b_n)$ such that $b_n = o(1/n)$, it is possible to find $a_n$ such that $a_n > b_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

@Cactus Yes, I didn't really mean any $b_n$. See my answer for what is true.

By the way, there is no "maximal" convergent series : for all convergent series $\displaystyle\sum a_n$, denote $\displaystyle R_n = \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} a_k$. Then for every $0 < \alpha <1$, the series $$\sum \dfrac{a_n}{R_n^{\alpha}}$$ is still convergent, whereas $\displaystyle a_n = o \left( \dfrac{a_n}{R_n^{\alpha}}\right)$.

Let $b_n$ be positive numbers such that $nb_n \to 0$. There exists $n_k \to \infty$ such that $n_kb_{n_k} <\frac 1 {2^{k+1}}$. Take $a_n=2b_n$ if $n$ is of the form $n_k$ for some $k$ and (say) $\frac 1 {k^{3}}$ for all other $k$.  Then $\sum na_n <\infty$ but $a_n >b_n$ for infintely many $n$.
So a dominating sequence of the order of $(\frac 1 {n^{2}})$ is overly optimisitc.
